# How to check if specific file in folder of vim runtimepath is loaded or not?

Tags: vim

I am having some trouble with the addition of a snippet file and I would like to check whether this specific file is being loaded or not.

I know all the snippets from the package vim-snippets are in `D:\Users\username\vimfiles\pack\minpac\start\vim-snippets\snippets` and I have put my new and personalized snippet file in `D:\Users\username\vimfiles\snippets`

I have checked that the folder `D:\Users\username\vimfiles\snippets` is at the beginning of the `runtimepath`

```
echo $rtp
```

I have checked the output of `:scripts` but I cannot see any of the snippets files being read.

How do I check if a specific file has been in one of the folders from vim `runtimepath` has been loaded or not?

Comment: In general, snippet files are not sourced like regular `*.vim` files. Their content is directly read and parsed by third-party scripts without Vim's knowledge so there is no Vim-native way to know if a specific snippet file was loaded or not. You will have to go through your snippet expansion plugin's documentation to see if they expose some method for retrieving that information… and maybe hack something of your own if they don't.

Comment: @romainl The hack you propose could be a good hint. Could it be a good approach to define an autocmd-events like FileReadPre/Post or SourcePre/SourceCmd in order to write a message when we have to deal with scripts written in vim language? (Obviously, I should check first in the plugin the way the files are being read/loaded)

Comment: The problem, here, is that the snippet files are really foreign data. The snippet expansion plugins probably use `:help readfile()` but calling that function doesn't trigger any event that could be used in an autocommand so, unless the plugin already does something along those lines, this is a dead end. Checking if the plugin defines a buffer-local variable could be another idea. Maybe even attempting the expansion of a known snippet via `:help feedkeys()`.